# Creating Tabs in React Native using TabBarIOS

Tags: ios, react-native, tabbarios

I am new to React and trying to follow [this Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/react-native-introduction/).Apparently, It's for an older version of react-native. so Im following and tweaking the code when it's not working. I'm using `ReactNative 0.41`.

**my index.ios.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    TabBarIOS
} from 'react-native';
import Featured from './Featured';
import Search from './Search';

class BookSearch extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedTab: 'featured'
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
                <TabBarIOS.Item
                    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'featured'}
                    icon={{uri:'featured'}}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            selectedTab: 'featured'
                        });
                    }}>
                    <Featured/>
                </TabBarIOS.Item>
                <TabBarIOS.Item
                    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'search'}
                    icon={{uri:'search'}}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            selectedTab: 'search'
                        });
                    }}>
                    <Search/>
                </TabBarIOS.Item>
            </TabBarIOS>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('BookSearch', () => BookSearch);
```

**and here is the Error:**

[image: json value'{uri =featured;}' of type NSMutableDictionary cannot be converted to an image. File not Found]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected the error was due to syntax change. the new version uses `systemIcon='featured'` instead of `icon={{uri:'featured'}}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong in entering uri of the icon. variable 'featured' is not defined.

I can see there are more errors such as your entry for selectedtab is wrong.

Cheers :)

Comment: 'featured' is not a variable I figured that the syntax has changed from 
`icon={{uri:'featured'}}` to `icon='featured'`

Comment: oh sorry i mean that only, anyways happy to know you solved it. :)